# Multiplying without using * operator

Tags: c

I am trying for a code that multiplies two numbers and that should not use * operator. I wrote this code but doesn't gives an expected solution.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int ar,char *arg[])
{
   long int a;
   long int b;

   sscanf(arg[1],"%ld",&a);
   sscanf(arg[2],"%ld",&b);

   long int count=0;
   long int temp=b;
   long int prod=0;

   while(temp>0)
   {
       count=0;

       while(temp/2>0)
       {
          temp/=2;
          count++;
       }

       prod+=a<<(count);
       temp=b-(1<<count);
   }

   //printf("%ld %d\n",count,1<<count);
   printf("%ld\n",prod);
   return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please explain whats wrong in the code?

Comment: Couldn't wait.. Next time please do it yourself.

Comment: Hint: your code would likely work for inputs like `2^n`.

Comment: Is not it to complicated ? I mean 3 * 2 it is just 3+3 => for(int i =0 ; i<b ;++i) prod = prod + b;

Comment: This surely has an asymptotic behavior of O(my god).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your while loop this way.

```
while(temp>0)
{
    count=0;
    while(temp/2>0)
    {
        temp/=2;
        count++;
    }
    prod+=a<<(count);
    temp=b-(1<<count);
    b=temp  //<--
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While vinayawsm has given the solution. I thought that you might want to consider solving it from the LSB up. =D

```
   while(b>0)
   {
       if (b % 2 == 1)
          prod+=a;

       a=a<<1;
       b=b>>1;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   class Multiply
       {
             public static void main(String [] args)
              {
                   int a,b,value=0;
                   a=7;
                   b=4;
                   for(int i=1;i<=b;i++){
                   value+=a;
              }
             System.out.println("Multiplication is:\t" + value);
        }
```